# Augmenting type aliases in elm or haskell

Tags: haskell, elm

Say I have a type in elm (0.18) like this:

```
type alias CatSimple = 
  { color : String
  , age : Int 
  , name : String
  , breed : String
}
```

My project requires that I also have a type that has all the fields of the previous one, but with a few additional fields:

```
type alias CatComplex =
  { color : String
  , age : Int 
  , name : String
  , breed : String
  , feral : Bool
  , spayed : Bool
}
```

Now let's say that I need to add another field to `CatSimple`.  I would have to remember to add it to `CatComplex` as well.

I would like to be able to dynamically augment my types so that I can avoid having to update all of them, or having to resort to something like this:

```
type alias CatComplex =
  { simpleData: CatSimple
  , feral : Bool
  , spayed : Bool
}
```

Is there any way to do that in Elm?

If not, does Haskell provide a way to do this?

Comment: [Potentially relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370593/3234959)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use extensible records in Elm to define a rudimentary sort of field composition:

```elm
type alias Cat c =
    { c
        | color : String
        , age : Int
        , name : String
        , breed : String
    }

type alias FeralCat =
    Cat
        { feral : Bool
        , spayed : Bool
        }
```

Here's an example of how it could be used:

```elm
feralCatSummary : FeralCat -> String
feralCatSummary { color, feral } =
    color ++ "; Feral? " ++ toString feral

main : Html msg
main =
    text <|
        feralCatSummary
            { color = "Blue"
            , age = 5
            , name = "Billy"
            , breed = "Bluecat"
            , feral = True
            , spayed = False
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, but there are some things you can do that go in the direction you want:

Have a single type but make the extra info 'optional'

```
type alias Cat =
  { color : String
  , age : Int 
  , name : String
  , breed : String
  , feral : Maybe Bool
  , spayed : Maybe Bool
 }
```

When you want to pass CatComplex to a function that only uses the Cat fields you could define a Type

```
 type alias CatGeneric a =       
    { a| 
          color : String
          , age : Int 
          , name : String
          , breed : String 
      }
```

then

```
fn : CatGeneric a -> Bool 
....
```

and this should type check if you pass either a Cat or a CatComplex