# Can I type a partial record?

Tags: haskell, types, record

I have a `Person` record with a name and an id, and a function `createPerson` that returns a `Person` without `id`, leaving generating the UUID to the caller.:

```
-- Person.hs
import Data.UUID (UUID)

data Person = Person { name :: String, id :: UUID }

createPerson name = Person { name = name }
```

**Is there a way type a `Person` without an `id`, to inform the Caller that `id Person` will throw an exception?** I've considered defining a `PartialPerson` as follows:

```
data PartialPerson = { name :: String }
```

but this quickly gets cumbersome when I want to add or change fields.

Comment: An easy type for a record that is missing its id would be `UUID -> Person`. The problem is that you can't print it or inspect its other fields.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider [using a parametric type for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370593/3234959).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible type for persons without id would be:

```
type PersonWithoutId = UUID -> Person
```

The problem is that we can't print values of this type, or inspect their other fields, because functions are opaque.

---

Another option is to parameterize the type:

```
data Person a = Person { name :: String, personId :: a }
type PersonWithId = Person UUID
type PersonWithoutId = Person ()
```

The nice thing about this is that you still can easily derive useful typeclasses.

---

A third option is to remove the id from the person and just use a pair when needed:

```
type PersonWithId = (UUID,Person)
```

or with a dedicated type:

```
data WithId a = WithId { theId :: UUID, theValue :: a } deriving Functor
```

The problem with this third option is that it becomes more cumbersome to have functions that work with both varieties of persons.

Also, auto-derived `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` instances will possibly have undesired nesting.

And it's not very extensible when there's more than one optional property.

Comment: Relevant talk (2016) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHjIl81HgfE

Comment: One more option: `data Person f = Person { name :: String, uuid :: f UUID }; type PersonWithId = Person Identity; type PersonWithoutId = Person (Const ())`. It looks similar to your second option, but has some [attractive generalizable operations](https://www.benjamin.pizza/posts/2017-12-15-functor-functors.html).

Comment: Besides the "rank2classes" library http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes mentioned in the link, another library which supports that style of programming is "barbies" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies

Answer (score 5):

**First way:**

You can define `Person` with `Maybe UUID`:

```hs
data Person = Person { name :: String, id :: Maybe UUID }
```

Now you can define some useful functions:

```hs
partialPerson :: String -> Person
partialPerson n = Person { name = n, id = Nothing }

getId :: Person -> UUID
getId (Person _ (Just uuid)) = uuid
getId _ = error "person hasn't UUID"
```

But `getId` is unsafe function, so you must be careful when you use it.

**Second way:**

You can define new data-type:

```hs
data PartialPerson = PartialPerson { name :: String }
```

... and define such functions for converting between this types:

```hs
withId :: PartialPerson -> UUID -> Person
withId (PartialPerson n) uuid = Person n uuid

withoutId :: Person -> PartialPerson
withoutId (Person n _) = PartialPerson n
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would define `getId` when `id :: Person -> Maybe UUID` already exists (ignoring the fact that `id` is probably not a good field name.)

Comment: @chepner why do you say `id` is not a good field name?

Comment: Because `id :: a -> a` is already a function.

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the idea of making `Person` parametric to support both persons with- and without id, whilst however keeping it rigid that the `id` field *is about UUIDs*, not just some arbitrary parameter type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs #-}

data IdRequirement
  = NoIdNeeded | IdOptional | IdRequired

data IdField (reqId :: IdRequirement) where
  IdLess :: IdField 'NoIdNeeded
  IdOmitted :: IdField 'IdOptional
  IdProvided :: UUID -> IdField 'IdOptional
  RequiredId ::  UUID -> IdField 'IdRequired

data Person (reqId :: IdRequirement)
  = Person { personName :: String
           , personId :: IdField reqId }
```